# my helper function throwing Message: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i have array, in this array  studentAbsentId i have in one more array, now i want to find the studentAbsentId 1 means what his name , suppose studentAbsentId 2 means what his name, so that purpose i written one function helper.php, but it is throwing error, how can fix this issue.

> My Controller

```
public function getAbsentListStaff() {
    $data = array(
        "schoolId" => $_POST['schoolName'],
        "classId" => $_POST['className'],
        "sectionId" => $_POST['sectionName'],
        "studentAbsentDate" =>$_POST['studentAbsentDate'],
    );

    $absentresponse= $this->Android_login_model->admin_options_listdisplayStaff($data);
    foreach($absentresponse as $absent){
        echo $id = $absent['studentAbsentId'];
        //echo getStudentnameById($id);
    } 

  }
```

> print_r($absentresponse);

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [absent_id] => 1
            [studentAbsentId] => 3
            [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-20
            [schoolId] => 2
            [classId] => 1
            [sectionId] => 1
            [morning] => 1
            [evening] => 1
            [updatedBy] => 1
            [updatedOn] => 2017-04-20
            [status] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [absent_id] => 2
            [studentAbsentId] => 4
            [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-20
            [schoolId] => 2
            [classId] => 1
            [sectionId] => 1
            [morning] => 1
            [evening] => 
            [updatedBy] => 1
            [updatedOn] => 2017-04-20
            [status] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [absent_id] => 3
            [studentAbsentId] => 5
            [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-20
            [schoolId] => 2
            [classId] => 1
            [sectionId] => 1
            [morning] => 1
            [evening] => 
            [updatedBy] => 1
            [updatedOn] => 2017-04-20
            [status] => 0
        )

)
```

> helper.php / under helper folder

```
 if ( ! function_exists('getStudentnameById')){
   function getStudentnameById($id){
       $ci =& get_instance();
       $ci->load->database();

       $ci->db->select('firstName');
       $ci->db->where('student_id', $id);
       $q = $ci->db->get('new_student')->result();
       return $q[0]->firstName; // particulart filed
   }
}
```

From here if i will print studentAbsentId means it is working , but i need firstname of that id, how can solve this issue?

Comment: `print_r($q)` and post the data

Comment: print_r($q),returning empty array , but what i am written that is correct only

Comment: `echo $id` and see having data on it

Comment: Yes, data is coming in loop , like 1,2,3....

Comment: in loop ?? post example

Comment: echo getStudentnameById(1); if i give the static value 1 or 2 means print_r($q) returning correct data like Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstName] => Janardhan 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstName] => Janardhan 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstName] => Janardhan 
        )

)

Comment: I am using foreach loop

Comment: show how its coming to this. `echo $id` works ?

Comment: See my array , i have 3 records, now i want display his name,how can do this, in this array i have student id only

Comment: everything seems ok. check table name and all. there may be some minor mistake

Answer (score 0):

Change this (in `getStudentnameById` function)

```
return $q[0]->firstName;
```

as following

```
$first_name = isset($q[0]->firstName) ? $q[0]->firstName : '';
return $first_name;
```

Because your loop will continue 3 times as there are 3 element in your array but in `new_student` table data could be not available for each `$id` then it will through error. Once you check by `isset()` it will return data only if data found otherwise empty string will be returned.

However you may return any demo data when data not found like

```
$first_name = isset($q[0]->firstName) ? $q[0]->firstName : 'no name';
```

**Another way**

Try this

```
if ( ! function_exists('getStudentnameById')){
   function getStudentnameById($id){
       $ci =& get_instance();
       $ci->load->database();

       $ci->db->select('firstName');
       $ci->db->where('student_id', $id);
       $q = $ci->db->get('new_student')->result();
       if(!empty($q)){
         $first_name = $q[0]->firstName;
       }else{
         $first_name = 'no data';
       }
       return $first_name;
   }
}
```